# How to export Firefox plugins & Settings to other users?

Tags: firefox, users, settings, browser, firefox-extensions

How do I export Firefox Plugins, Settings & the changes that I have made to about:config in Admin Account to all the Standard User Accounts, right now I have to manually install all the plugins, change settings, make changes to the about:config for every Standard User Account.

Comment: See this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tar up the `.mozilla` folder you want to use for all users, and untar it to all the accounts you wish to copy the settings/profile/extensions to. For example, if you want to copy the Firefox settings/extensions/profiles of the `root` user to users `john` and `jane`:

```
sudo -s
cd /root/
tar -czvf mozilla.tar.gz .mozilla
tar -zxvf /root/mozilla.tar.gz -C /home/john
tar -zxvf /root/mozilla.tar.gz -C /home/jane
chown -R john:john /home/john/.mozilla
chwon -R jane:jane /home/jane/.mozilla
```

If you have a large number of users, you could always write a script to untar `/root/mozilla.tar.gz` to each user's home directory:

```
for dest in `find /home/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -not -path '*/\.*' -not -path '*/lost+found' -printf '%f\n'`; 
do 
  tar -zxf "/root/mozilla.tar.gz" -C "/home/$dest"
  chown -R "$dest:$dest" "/home/$dest/.mozilla"
done
```

**IMPORTANT:** The above will not work if users have encrypted home folders, and they're not signed in. It also assumes the users' home directories have the same name as their usernames. If user `john`'s home directory is `/home/johnsmith`, the above script will not work.